# Solr import from sql not indexing latin accents or "ñ"

Tags: encoding, solr, dataimporthandler

I am using Solr 3.6 and importing my data from SQL Server 2008.

I have words with Latin Accents and "ñ" and I need them to be indexed that way (not replacing them with the non-accent equivalent letter or "n" in the "ñ" case).
Those words are currently indexed with weird characters such as "Ã±".

I know it´s an encoding issue, but I can´t touch the data base encoding (and even if I could, I have no idea if that's even possible).

Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to fix it by specifying your database encoding in the JDBC URL.